# Ipad app with two UIWebViews

Tags: ipad, uiwebview, hyperlink

I have an iPad app with two UIWebviews, one on top of the other. Is there a way to have all the links that are clicked in one, open in only the other view?

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the delegate for your first `UIWebView`:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        [otherWebView loadRequest:request];

        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Is this a built in method of the UIWebView Class?

Comment: Oh, where should I place this method? I have an AppDelegate and a ViewController class only.

Comment: This is a method your `UIWebView` calls on the object you have set as its `delegate`. This method is specified in the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol this object should use. Which of your two classes this is, depends on what you set as the `UIWebView` 's `delegate`.